# How to override a subclass of book to get TOC on even page?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, double-sided

I am trying to get my table of contents on a verso page (i.e., an even-numbered one). I have seen several threads on similar topics here, and many of them recommend making your own command more or less like this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\clearevenpage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

This doesn't work for my document. I have also tried the solution based on the changepage and ifthen packages posted [in this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56377/11665). If I just put `\null\clearpage` or `\hbox{}\newpage` before the `\tableofcontents` command, I just clears to a recto (odd-numbered) page instead so that I just get an extra blank page.

I am using [this subclass](http://www.nt.ntnu.no/users/skoge/group/latex-for-phd-thesis/ntnuthesis.tar.gz) of the book class. I don't see anything in [the cls file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/228495/ntnuthesis.cls) that obviously would cause this behavior, but I'm not that good at reading Latex code, so I'm probably missing something. Or is it the book class itself?

Comment: You are using the `book` class and the `\tableofcontents` makes use of `\chapter*{}` to produce the *Contents*. Since new chapters start on odd pages you have that effect.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. For example, it's not clear if you're using `twoside` as an option.

Comment: The "ToC starts on an odd page" convention is very old, and universal. That is why it is ingraned into LaTeX. Sure, you *can* go against hallowed convention, but you should have an extremely good reason to do so.

Comment: I generally agree, @vonbrand. My document is still in the draft stage, so I might change this later. The reason I want the TOC on a verso page in my current draft is that the TOC is now two pages long, and this makes it easier to get an overview of it in my pdf reader. I thought of this when I recently saw somebody start his TOC on a verso page in his printed and bound PhD thesis. It struck me as clumsy at first, but I can see the arguments for doing so — especially if the TOC is two or four pages long.

Comment: My reason is that I am translating a book from German to English and in the original German book the table of contents is on a left (even) page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class `ntnuthesis` loads class `book`. There `\tableofcontents` is defined using `\chapter*`. All `\chapter` commands calls `\cleardoublepage`.

The definition of `\cleardoublepage` can be changed to execute `\clearevenpage` instead for the duration of `\tableofcontents`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\clearevenpage}{%
  \clearpage
  \if@twoside
    \ifodd\c@page
      \hbox{}%
      \newpage
      \if@twocolumn
        \hbox{}%
        \newpage
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
First page
\begingroup
  \let\cleardoublepage\clearevenpage
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup
\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

Three pages are the result:

1. "First page"
2. "Table of contents"
3. "First chapter"

If you just want to allow chapters to start on even and odd pages, then you can use option `openany`:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{openany}{book}
\documentclass[twoside]{ntnuthesis}
```

Comment: Super, it's simple and works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Redefining `\cleardoublepage` to be `\clearpage` locally should work.

Call `\tableofcontents` in this way:

```
{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage\tableofcontents}
```

MWE (you can substitute `book` with `ntnuthesis`)

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}

{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage\tableofcontents}

\chapter{1st}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\chapter{2nd}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]

Comment: It works since the redefinition is inside the block with `{}`? Am I right? Nice!

Comment: @Sigur of course, otherwise the change is not local...